# Where can I Store json file for use after building the app in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Is there any specific folder where I can store my files so that the app can use it later after building? Like Meteor has a private folder, is there any folder for node webkit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requiring/running JavaScript outside of node-webkit application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746570/requiring-running-javascript-outside-of-node-webkit-application)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no predefined path and it is not needed. You can access any file with relative path from current dir. Just do not forget to add it into final build.